# Cable length for Google Server

Tags: networking

I wish to connect my Google Server in one room to a switch in another room using `ethernet cat 5e` cable.
What is the maximum cable length I can use between both nodes to avoid high RTT?

Answer (score -2):

You can use upto 100 meters of cable but i'll suggest you to do not use a cable longer than 80 meters.